# Ruby/Redcarpet: strip markdown from text

Tags: ruby, markdown, redcarpet

I'm writing a Ruby app and it currently uses [redcarpet](https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet) to render Markdown.

I need to strip Markdown markup from a text. Any easy way to do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it's possible with the `Redcarpet::Render::StripDown` Class  -> https://rubydoc.info/gems/redcarpet/Redcarpet/Render/StripDown

It says "Turns Markdown into plaintext"

Comment: Thanks! D'oh! Should have searched better.

Comment: I ran into an `Uninitialized constant: Redcarpet::Render::StripDown` error, but adding `require 'redcarpet/render_strip'` fixed it; see https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet/issues/138